# Using R-command dnorm to find the expected value of counts

Tags: r, math, statistics

I have tried to multiple R-commands to find the answer but I am obviously using the wrong command.

I am using the following:

```
dnorm(15)
```

How should I add the parameters? I've tried to plot 'mat' inside, also just the second row for product B. Any suggestions?

```
mat <- matrix(c(24, 21, 14,
12, 15, 22,
15, 26, 24), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
colnames(mat) <- c("Low","Medium","High")
rownames(mat) <- c("A","B","C")
```

What is the expected value of counts in the ”Medium” rating category for product ”B” under
the null hypothesis?

**Choices:**

1. 0.087
2. 15.0
3. 16.3
4. 17.6
5. 19.1

Comment: I still don't don't know what's use of the **Choices** here. Please clarify what's the  input and your desired result.

Comment: @PeaceWang is right: your question is very unclear.  But it looks as if you're being asked to perform (part of) a chi-squared test on your data table.  If so, your use of `dnorm` is inappropriate.  If I'm right, you can do the necessary arthmetic on a calculator, or even with paper and pencil.  Hint: you need to think about the row sums, the column sums and the grand total.

Comment: That doesn't look like a generic R language or statistics question but as if you were doing a test and you expect someone else to solve it for you. Try to formulate a generic question on the topic and maybe then you'll get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not fully self-evident. I hope the following helps, but check what type of statistics, etc. you are talking/having to work with.

For a simple homogeneity χ2–test, the expected values are simply calculated from the corresponding column (C), row (R) and grand (N) totals: E = (R * C) / N.

For your case this results in the following:

```
# calculate row/column totals
addmargins(mat)
    Low Medium High Sum
A    24     21   14  59
B    12     15   22  49
C    15     26   24  65
Sum  51     62   60 173
```

For the "*... expected value of counts in the ”Medium” rating category for product ”B”...*".

```
E_15 = (49 * 62) / 173
E_15
[1] 17.56069
```

And hence answer/choice 4 is what you are looking for (given the assumption I made).